# RestTemplate execute() method cannot send JSON Payload

Tags: spring, resttemplate

In my application, I need to take data from another request and chain into a new one

I must use the `exchange()` method of `RestTemplate` because I have issue with jacksons lib and I cannot add/change the libs.

this is my code:

```
 final RequestCallback requestCallback = new RequestCallback() {
                @Override
                public void doWithRequest(final ClientHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                    request.getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

                    // Add basic auth header
                    String auth        = username + ":" + password;
                    byte[] encodedAuth = Base64Utils.encode(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
                    String authHeader  = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);
                    request.getHeaders().add("Authorization", authHeader);

                    // Add Headers Request
                    Enumeration headerNamesReq = servletRequest.getHeaderNames();
                    while (headerNamesReq.hasMoreElements()) {
                        String headerName = (String) headerNamesReq.nextElement();
                        if (whiteListedHeaders.contains(headerName.toLowerCase())) {
                            String headerValue = servletRequest.getHeader(headerName);
                            request.getHeaders().add(headerName, headerValue);
                        }
                    }

                    request.getHeaders().forEach((name, value) -> {
                        log.info("RestExecutorMiddleware", "HEADERS ---\t" + name + ":" + value);
                    });

                    IOUtils.copy(new ByteArrayInputStream(payload.getBytes()), request.getBody());
                }
            };

            // Factory for restTemplate
            SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
            requestFactory.setBufferRequestBody(false);
            restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);


            ClientHttpResponse responsePost = restTemplate.execute(url, method, requestCallback, new ResponseFromHeadersExtractor());
```

But at the end, the endpoint cannot receive my JSON (receive data, but not JSON.)

Where I wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Very inaccuracy code. Make all steps one-to-one and it will work, you make optimization later ...

1. Basic Auth. Don't do unnecessary actions
   var headers = new HttpHeaders();
   headers.setBasicAuth(username, password);
   That's all, Spring will take care of everything else - to apply Base64, add `Basic:` and set properly a header.
2. Set all required headers including `headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`
3. Get an entity/object which you need to send (set as a body) with a request.
4. Serialize your object. The most popular, proper and simple way is using fasterxml json framework, you can make serialization with `mapper.writeBalueAsString(<your object>)`. If you really cannot use external libraries, HttpEntity should make it: `var request = new HttpEntity<>(<object>, headers);`
5. Make restTemplate request. In almost all cases more convenient methods are `restTemplate.postForObject()`, `restTemplate.getForObject()`, `restTemplate.postForEntity()`, etc.: `restTemplate.postForObject(uri, request, ResponseObject.class)`